# Calculate $\iiint_V (15x+30z)\,dx\,dy\,dz$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> Calculate
> $$\iiint_V (15x+30z)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
> where
> $$V: \begin{cases}z = x^2+3y^2,\ \  z = 0 \\ y=x,\ \  y=0,\ \  x=1 \end{cases}$$

- I tried $x = r\cos\left(t\right), \ \ y = r\sin\left(t\right), \ \ z = h$, then obviously
  $t \in \left[0, \pi/4\right]$ and
  $h \in \left[0, r^{2}\left[\cos^{2}\left(t\right) + 3\sin^{2}\left(t\right)\right]\right]$.
- However, I cannot set the interval for $r$.
- The triangular shape formed by $x=1$ makes it difficult for me.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, there is no need to convert this into polar coordinates at all. What is the region you see in xy-plane?

Comment: @MathLover It is a triangle. So is it $x\in[0,1]$, $y \in [0, x]$, and $z \in [0, x^2+3y^2]$?

Comment: Yes that is it!

Comment: @MathLover Thank you. I don't know why I was going with the change of variables.

Comment: Your $\displaystyle V:\left\{\right.$-definition is not quite clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

$x = r\cos\theta\\y=r\sin\theta\\z=h$

Substitute these into the equations for the boundary.

$h = r^2\cos^2 \theta  + 3r^2\sin^2\theta\\
r\sin\theta = r\cos\theta\\
r\sin\theta = 0\\
r\cos\theta = 1$

What can we simplify?

$\sin\theta = \cos\theta\\
\theta= \frac {\pi}{4}$

$r\sin\theta = 0\\
\theta = 0,\text{ or } r = 0$

But you have all of these.

As for that boundary for $r.$

$r\cos\theta = 1\\
r = \sec\theta$

$\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{4}}\int_0^{\sec\theta}\int_0^{r^2(\cos^2\theta + 3\sin^2\theta)} r\ dz\ dr\ d\theta$